# Automatically log user out on browser close with remember me unchecked - devise, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails and devise.  I want the user to be automatically and instantly logged out on browser close.  The way I understand it, in rails, the cookie generated by the session method should expire immediately on browser close.  I can't find where devise is making the session if it is at all.  I see there is a timeoutable option but I don't want that.  If remember me is unchecked I want the user to have to log in again if the browser is closed.

How can I get this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445846/1162683) and delete the cookie before the browser closes:

```
<% if current_user.present? && !current_user.remember_me %>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode(){
   document.cookie = '_' + rails_app_name_here + '_session' +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
   return null;
}
</script>
<% end %>
```

You could put this in your application layout before the closing body if you wanted.

If you can't make this work, you might be SOL.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should disable devise :rememberable and handle sessions and cookies myself.  What do you think?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what you gain by doing that yourself. I think devise generates a consistently named cookie, all you need to do is delete it.

Comment: Where would I put the code you pasted above?  I'm also having trouble finding the name of the cookie.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The above didn't work.  Any other ideas?  Maybe the name of the cookie isn't correct.  How can I find the name of the cookie that I need to set the expiration date for?

Comment: Use chrome inspector to see what cookies are being created when you login.

Comment: Looks like it's named correctly.  The cookie shows expiration set to when "when the browsing session ends" which isn't true because when I close out the browser, the cookie persists.  Not quite sure how this is working under the hood in devise and what to try next.

Comment: It actually seems to work normally with firefox.  This might be a chrome bug that doesn't delete temporary cookies on browser close.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22776628/4584963

Comment: The http only cookie could be an issue as well https://alainahardie.com/logging-out-of-a-rails-app-that-uses-session_store-cookie_store/ also maybe just editing the cookie to a bad value could work if chrome refuses to delete cookies and considers it a feature